# Правила выбора меток для вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, метки, правки

Хотелось бы обсудить и выработать для всех участников сообщества правила выбора меток при задании вопроса и его редактировании.

Как известно, у вопроса может быть от одной до пяти меток одновременно. Автор вопроса в первую очередь заинтересован в выборе правильных меток, чтобы его вопрос был замечен участниками, имеющими подписку на соответствующие метки, и в итоге получил ответ максимально быстро.

Обычно, одной-двух меток достаточно, чтобы определить предметную область. Применительно к SO это значит: язык программирования, фреймворк, библиотеку и т.п. Такие метки можно назвать основными. Хотя по сути, все метки в вопросе равноправны, но при редактировании вопроса (а может и просто при отображении) выводятся (пересортировываются) согласно текущей популярности.

Когда ответ получен и принят, автору вопроса уже не так важны правильные метки на нём, т.к. его проблема решена. Но эти метки становятся важны тем, кто столкнётся с подобной задачей в будущем, или просто захочет пополнить свои знания в какой-то конкретной области, возможно, достаточно узкой. И вот тут-то, как мне кажется, играет значение наличие вспомогательных меток. По которым можно довольно быстро найти вопросы, используя [страницу поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search).

Применимо к метке [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), такими вспомогательными метками могут быть [конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) или [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b), а может быть даже [const](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/const).

И вот сам вопрос: должны ли эти вспомогательные метки действительно быть у вопроса, или они только засоряют вопрос и никто по ним искать информацию не будет?

Для меня лично этот вопрос кажется довольно странным, а ответ на него очевидным. Я уже высказался о своём мнении на этот счёт двумя абзацами выше. Но может быть кто-то считает иначе. Как минимум один такой участник точно есть, надеюсь он тоже выскажется в этой теме и попробует убедить меня и других участников в своей версии.

Через [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) к лучшему будущему *Stack Overflow на русском*!

Всё таки приведу ссылку на правку, которая послужила толчком для публикации данного вопроса. [Вот она, под номером 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/596870/revisions). Ни о каких `new`, `register`, `delete` речи там нет. А `const` следует рассматривать не как ключевое слово языка, а как концепцию. Для примера, можете посмотреть [описание метки `const` на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/const/info).

Comment: «*А const следует рассматривать не как ключевое слово языка, а как концепцию*» откуда это следует? И да, в вопросе речь шла о практике по избежанию ошибок, и к концепции неизменности(immutability), этот вопрос вообще не имеет никакого отношения. Другие метки я привел для примера, мы же ситуацию в общем рассматриваем, не правда ли?

Comment: @ixSci как это, не имеет отношения к концепции неизменности? Цитирую: `чтобы нельзя было написать (a+b)=c или ещё как-то испортить полученный результат` т.к. `(a+b)` не модифицируема! Следует из описания метки на enSO, например. Т.к. я не считаю правильным, если метка на enSO будет значить совершенно другое нежели одноименная (синонимичная) метка на ruSO. Ситуацию конечно рассматриваем в общем, но причиной послужил именно конкретный частный случай, который Вы обобщаете со всеми остальными. А мне кажется, его нельзя обобщать, т.к. `new`,`register`,`delete` != `константность`, `конструктор`

Comment: Ну, вот так — не имеет. Что я и показал в своём ответе, там нет const, но достигается желаемый эффект: исключить возможную ошибку, по использованию временного объекта неправильным образом. В том вопросе нет ни константности, ни конструктора — они ортогональны вопросу. Что касается enSO — они пусть пишут, что хотят. Равно как и здешнее описание меток это никак не руководство к действию. Чтобы принят описание метки нужно 2 человека, почему я должен считать мнение этих 2 человек правильным? Более того, я крайне редок захожу в описание меток и видя const интерпретирую его однозначно — ключевое.

Comment: @ixSci способ достижения желаемого эффекта - это ответ. А метки относятся к вопросу. Если Ваш ответ решает проблему без `const`, то это ещё не значит, что `const` лишний в вопросе. Вот Вы говорите, что можно проигнорировать мнения 2 человек при правке метки, но, почему-то забываете, что Ваша правка вообще была внесена единолично. Что ж, заходите чаще в описание меток, они не просто так присутствуют (когда присутствуют), а именно чтобы картина была единой для всех участников, кто их использует, добавляет или удаляет. ruSO - дочерний сайт, не опираться на опыт enSO не получится.

Comment: Я единолично меняю теги, потому что мне позволяет система. Если Вы считаете, что изначальный вопрос имел отношение именно к константности, что ж, тут я уже ничего не могу поделать.

Answer (score 5):

[конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), [const](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/const), [register](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register), [delete](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete), [new](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new) и т.п. являются частью языка C++ и покрываются меткой [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). <s>Эти метки просто бесполезны, они не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки.</s> Если какое-то из этих *ключевых* слов используется в вопросе — его найдут и без метки. Засорять же вопросы подобными метками, а также другими «мусорными» метками типа [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf)(ничего против вопросов по ООП не имею, просто метку вставляют в вопросы, где есть классы).

Поэтому, когда я вижу, что такие метки есть я их удаляю — они не нужны.

Другое дело метки типа [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c),[метапрограммирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и т.п. Они говорят о том, что человека интересует конкретная и *обширная* часть языка, они конкретизируют вопрос и позволяют привлечь тех, кто специализируется на подобных темах.

---

**UPD:** В изначальном варианте я выразился не совсем точно: я не имею в виду, что эти метки вообще бесполезны. Я имею в виду, что они бесполезны вне конкретного вопроса по `new`, `delete` и т.п. Если вопрос не стоит по ключевому слову `const`, то метка `const` не нужна. Вот о чём я говорю.

Comment: Добавлю, что `new` есть и в C++, и в Java, но реализация настолько отличается, что переносить какие-то решения из одного языка в другой не вполне корректно. А знания, например, о многопоточности достаточно универсальны. Опыт разработки многопоточных приложений на C++ может быть очень полезен в том же самом на Java.

Comment: @NickVolynkin замечу, что в вопросе про `new` не было ни слова. А [tag:const] подразумевает не ключевое слово языка c++, а немодифицируемую сущность, характерную для многих языков. То что для метки еще нет описания - не повод её удалять. [tag:конструктор] тоже актуальная для многих языков метка, описывающая концепцию специальной функции для создания элементов. Рекомендую в частности обратить внимание на описание этих меток на enSO. Можно было бы понять замену одних меток другими, при достижении их максимального кол-ва, но если их просто удалить, стоит задуматься - какую пользу это принесет?

Comment: @alexolut, `const` вне контекста точно мусор, а вот `конструктор` (по аналогии с многопоточностью) можно  и оставить

Comment: @avp на основании чего у Вас такое однозначное утверждение про `const`? Вы метки на enSO смотрели? Почему они там существуют, а у нас их быть не должно?

Comment: @alexolut, на основании сугубо субъективных представлений о селективности терминов. На enSO же я вообще почти не смотрю.

Comment: @alexolut, посмотрел я описание `const` на enSO. Оно не применимо к C++, потому что в C++ `const` не означает, что сущность неизменна. Более того, такое описание полностью неверно для JS, где `const` можно менять! Поэтому, описание `const`  на enSO попросту вредно.

Comment: @ixSci всегда можно предложить правку, если считаете, что там что-то не так. Более того, в кратком описании фраза `"never changes"` не просто так взята в кавычки. И Вы прекрасно должны понимать о какой "константности" идёт речь. Я не хочу в комментариях спорить о корректности описания метки на enSO для всех языков, но быстрый гуглинг [говорит](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), что в ES-2015 JS `const` ведёт себя вполне ожидаемым образом.

Comment: @ixSci а какую позитивную роль Вы видите в выпиливании меток с вопроса, учитывая, что в вопросе так или иначе затронута тема, на которую ссылается метка?

Comment: @alexolut, роль та же, что и при удалении приветствий и прочего: уменьшение визуального шума.

Comment: @ixSci приветствия и пр. не привносят вообще никакой полезной информации, и отнимают лишнее время при чтении. А вот наличие метки, актуальной для вопроса, позволяет дополнительно классифицировать вопросы, совершенно не съедая при этом время на ознакомление с сутью. Более того, даже проясняя его суть без прочтения основного текста. Обычно, заинтересованный участник читает вопросы, которые **уже** выделены цветом на основании его предпочтений по меткам. Т.е. метки как таковые читать вообще не приходится. Они нужны только для выборки списка вопросов.

Comment: @alexolut, я не понимаю, почему Вы пытаетесь меня убедить в том, что метки не мешают, когда я говорю, что они *мне* мешают. Для меня они создают визуальный шум. Если я удаляю метку, значит с моей точки зрения она в вопросе лишняя. Я никогда не удаляю метки просто ради удаления оных. К примеру, зачем нужна метка .net в вопросе по C#? C# подразумевает .net. И т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Метки нужны для поиска. Тот же запрос `[C++] [new]` даст куда более релевантные результаты, чем `[c++] new`. Поэтому такие метки полезны, но только в том случае, если `new` - это именно то, о чём спрашивается в вопросе. Лепить его на всё подряд, где есть new, точно не надо.

Comment: я с этим согласен. Если вопрос конкретно по `new`, то я не считаю такую метку лишней. Но, как показывает практика, человек просто натыкивает метки по всем ключевым словам и понятиям, что есть у него в коде, а не по которым у него вопрос.

Comment: @ixSci, в таком случае он упрётся в лимит из 5 меток. А лишнее может и отвечающий подчистить.

Comment: О чём, собственно, и речь. Я удалил из вопроса лишние метки. Вот и всё.

Comment: @ixSci, но в ответе ты пишешь _"Эти метки просто бесполезны, они не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки"_

Comment: Обновил ответ. Несколько неправильно я выразил мысль.

Comment: @ixSci, да, тогда согласен. Держи плюс :)